# REST API, PATCH command and returning calculated fields

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

This could be newbie question.

I'm trying to write a REST API and I'm not entirely sure what is the best way to handle following scenario:

User changes a Quantity field in the "ordered products" grid and I fire an AJAX on blur like...

```
http://example.com/myapi/v1/orders/1/lineItem/1
PATCH 
POST DATA - [Qty:5]
```

Now I've this complex logic at server that calculates special levy and has to return that number to be displayed back in the grid to the user.

**Question**

Now should I return the entire set of properties for the order-item in question or just the ones that have been changed say, special levy and last updated flags)? What is the right approach here?

Comment: I'd return only the changed ones, but I guess there is no restriction about this. I'd read the [PATCH RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789) if I where you. Pls let me know the results.